# Inner class cannot construct new instance of other inner class

Tags: java

I have a class called `Scraper` with a static inner class `Builder`, and also a non-static inner class called `StringPair`, I'm trying to get one of the builder methods to construct a `new StringPair(a,b)` and add it to an `ArrayList<StringPair>`, however it doesn't compile, the compiler says `Error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context` and specifically highlights the `new StringPair(a,b)` as the source of the problem.

I don't understand what's wrong here, any help would be appreciated!

```
class Scraper {

    private final ArrayList<StringPair> stringPairs;

    Scraper(Builder builder) {

        stringPairs = builder.builderStringPairs;


    }

    public static class Builder {

        private static ArrayList<StringPair> builderStringPairs = new ArrayList<StringPair>();

        public Builder addStringPairs(String a, String b) {

            builderStringPairs.add(new StringPair(a, b));
            return this;
        }

        public Scraper build() {
            return new Scraper(this);
        }

    }

    class StringPair {
        String a,b;

        StringPair(String a, String b) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;

        }



        String getA() {
            return a;
        }
        String getB() {
            return b;
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Builder` isn't an inner class - it's just a *nested* class, with no implicit reference to an instance of the containing class (`Scraper`).

`StringPair`, however, *is* an inner class. In order to construct an instance of `StringPair`, you need to have a reference to an instance of `Scraper`. So, options for making `Builder` work:

- Make it an inner class (non-static)
- Make `StringPair` a nested class (static)
- Give `Builder` an instance somewhere, at which point you could use:

  ```
  builderStringPairs.add(instance.new StringPair(a, b));
  ```

I suspect the second option is the most appropriate one here - I can't see any reason why `StringPair` *needs* a reference to an instance of `Scraper`.

See [section 8.1.3 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3) for more information about nested and inner classes.

Comment: Thanks, I found the solution from your response. Actually I needed Builder to be static, since it's a builder, and I needed StringPair to be non-static, since I need to created instances of it for the ArrayList. So the problem was the static inner class cannot "see" the non-static inner class, so I just took out StringPair and made it a separate top-level class, and now it works.

Comment: @Sindikalis: You've misunderstood, and it's really important that you go back and look at this again to stop it being a problem next time. There's no need for `StringPair` to be non-static: "since I need to created instances of it for the ArrayList" does *not* suggest that it needs to be an inner class. You can still create instances of static nested classes - you're creating instances of Builder, after all. It just changes whether there's an implicit reference to an instance of the containing class.

Comment: Ok thanks I really appreciate your help! I guess I need to look into this a bit more.